# Azure Log Analytics 'where' operator: Failed to resolve table or column expression named 'SecurityEvent'

Tags: azure

Whenever I attempt to run the following Log Analytic query in Azure Log Analytics I get the following error:

> 'where' operator: Failed to resolve table or column expression named
>   'SecurityEvent'

I think it's because I need to enable `SecurityEvent` in `Log Analytics` but I'm not sure. I was wondering if someone could provide a guide;

```
SecurityEvent 
| where AccountType == "User" and EventID == 4625 and TimeGenerated > ago(6h) 
| summarize IPCount = dcount(IpAddress), makeset(IpAddress)  by Account
| where IPCount > 5
| sort by IPCount desc
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using the free version of security centre, there is no "SecurityEvent" item. You can use the schema explorer in Log Analytics to see that:

[image]